# Which error codes are safe for `slave_skip_errors` with MySQL Innodb

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, errors

Does anyone know which error codes are safe to ignore during replication, meaning the slave will remain consistent with the master?

For example

```
[mysqld]
slave-skip-errors=1007,1008,1050,1051,1054,1060,1061,1068,1094,1146
```

The example that I found omitted is [1213](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_lock_deadlock) (`Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, Error_code: 1213; handler error HA_ERR_LOCK_DEADLOCK`), which seems safe to me?

I've found little advice on the matter so seems like a good one for stackoverflow...

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't be skipping any errors. Skipping them is asking for trouble somewhere down the line. In 15+ years of MySQL replication experience, I've only used skip-errors once, and that was a particularly curious application issue, and they were all skipped manually, and not automatically. Be careful skipping errors...

Comment: Good point. Perhaps I should have just asked about 1213 only because the shorter the list the better and empty is ideal... no benefit adding a band aid for problems that aren't occuring

Comment: @KCD My opinion? never skip Deadlocks... It is a serious enough issue... One transaction was victim and wasn't processed. This can cause discrepancies in your database.  Not to scare you but to troubleshoot deadlocks can be very tedious.

Comment: I don't know any reason to skip errors except the intention to get inconsistent replica

Comment: @akuzminsky the point of this question is for those errors where the transaction rolls back

Comment: but rollbacks won't get into the binlog, right?

Comment: often the problem stops the slave so yes it is in the binlog... hardly seems helpful, these such problems should be dealt with on the master

Comment: often? I've never seen it. It must be a bug if it happens to you. Did you file one by any chance?

Comment: Instead of frequently, by often I meant to say many errors will replicate and stop the slave. Here are some examples of "`Last_Error`" that stopped the slave: `Could not execute Update_rows event on table db.sometable; Deadlock found...`, `Error 'Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.' on query.` and `Error 'Can't find file: './somedb/_sometable.frm' (errno: 2)' on query.`

Comment: Why would a deadlock on a slave happen if the relay log is replayed by a single thread?

Comment: Good question - unlike the others the deadlock error is actually only from a circular multi-master replication... I should remove it as it misleading. On that note, the answer regarding 1213 is no

Comment: Yet another reason not to use circular replication and not to write to both Masters in a dual-Master topology.

Answer (score 2):

To get the ball rolling, let us start with the manual

[option_mysqld_slave-skip-errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_slave-skip-errors)

> MySQL 5.7 supports an additional shorthand value ddl_exist_errors,
>   which is equivalent to the error code list
>   1007,1008,1050,1051,1054,1060,1061,1068,1094,1146.

Which includes:

1. Error: 1007 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_DB_CREATE_EXISTS)

   > Message: Can't create database '%s'; database exists
   >   An attempt to create a database failed because the database already exists.
   >   Drop the database first if you really want to replace an existing database, or add an IF NOT EXISTS clause to the CREATE DATABASE statement if to retain an existing database without having the statement produce an error.
2. Error: 1008 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_DB_DROP_EXISTS)

   > Message: Can't drop database '%s'; database doesn't exist
3. Error: 1050 SQLSTATE: 42S01 (ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR)

   > Message: Table '%s' already exists
4. Error: 1051 SQLSTATE: 42S02 (ER_BAD_TABLE_ERROR)

   > Message: Unknown table '%s'
5. Error: 1054 SQLSTATE: 42S22 (ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR)

   > Message: Unknown column '%s' in '%s'
6. Error: 1060 SQLSTATE: 42S21 (ER_DUP_FIELDNAME)

   > Message: Duplicate column name '%s'
7. Error: 1061 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_DUP_KEYNAME)

   > Message: Duplicate key name '%s'
8. Error: 1068 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_MULTIPLE_PRI_KEY)

   > Message: Multiple primary key defined
9. Error: 1094 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_NO_SUCH_THREAD)

   > Message: Unknown thread id: %lu
10. Error: 1146 SQLSTATE: 42S02 (ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE)

    > Message: Table '%s.%s' doesn't exist

But in support of Dave's comment:

> Normally, replication stops when an error occurs on the slave, which
>   gives you the opportunity to resolve the inconsistency in the data
>   manually. This option causes the slave SQL thread to continue
>   replication when a statement returns any of the errors listed in the
>   option value.
>
> Do not use this option unless you fully understand why you are getting
>   errors. If there are no bugs in your replication setup and client
>   programs, and no bugs in MySQL itself, an error that stops replication
>   should never occur. Indiscriminate use of this option results in
>   slaves becoming hopelessly out of synchrony with the master, with you
>   having no idea why this has occurred.

Comment: Another collection say something like "unsafe for replication".  Often these are overly cautious.